# Changing to SSL domain looses language in subdomain multi-store setup (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, cookies, ssl

I have the following Magento multi-store setup:

- german.domain.com
- english.domain.com
- french.domain.com

all are using

- secure.domain.com

as SSL domain. Cart and everything work fine except the language falls back to english!

If I am on german.domain.com (the store language is German) and I click on checkout the shop will be directed to secure.domain.com. The products I've added on german.domain.com are present but the language is not German anymore. It falls back to English! It does not deal with cookie Domain settings otherwise the products in the cart wouldn't be shared.

Does anybody have an idea or have solved this problem. I think there must be an intelligent coding to solve this.

Thanx

SOLUTION: Franklin P Strube gave the correct solution but I have hardcoded it in PHP in index.php:

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'secure.domain.com' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  $url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  if($url['host'] == 'german.domain.com') {
    setcookie('language', 'german', 0, '/', '.domain.com');
  } elseif($url['host'] == 'french.domain.com') {
    setcookie('language', 'french', 0, '/', '.domain.com');
  } else {
    setcookie('language', 'english', 0, '/', '.domain.com');
  }
}

if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'secure.domain.com') {
  if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
    $mageRunCode = $_COOKIE['language'];
  }
}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing multi-store setup, you usually have .htaccess rules like `SetEnvIf Host german.domain.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_com_de`. What do you have in your .htaccess file for multi-store?

My guess is that Magento is using English because the default website / store is loaded anytime you go to secure.domain.com. You can verify this by   adding `Mage::log("$mageRunCode $mageRunType");` just above the last line of the file where it is doing `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`. Make sure you have logging enabled in the System > Configuration > Developer area, then check what gets logged in magento/var/system.log. The solutions below may help you achieve what you want.

**Solution #1** Changing the "Add Store Code to Urls" setting in "System > Configuration > General > Web" may get you around this issue, but it could result in messy URLs.

**Solution #2** I can't remember how Magento handles language switching (there may be a magic query-string var to do this for you), but if you want to do this programmatically, you could do it all in htaccess via cookies and ENV vars:

```
# If they are coming from german domain, set the language cookie = german
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} german.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [CO=language:german]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} french.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [CO=language:french]

# Multistore routing (you probably already have this somewhere)
SetEnvIf Host german.domain.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=german
SetEnvIf Host french.domain.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=french

# Cookie language detection (using mod_rewrite, set the mage env)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=german
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:german]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} language=french
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:french]
```

Comment: FYI, the query string variable for setting the store is `___store`. This is checked in the  `Mage_Core_Model_App::_checkGetStore()` function found in the magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php file.

Comment: you are a genius! I have hardcoded your solution in PHP! I will update my post!

Answer (score -1):

Can you tell me the way how you achieve

I have the following Magento multi-store setup:

```
german.domain.com
english.domain.com
french.domain.com
```

all are using

```
secure.domain.com
```

as SSL domain.

We have created multiple website through folder in root directory and by creating website in admin by corresponding code.

But when we go for checkout for a product we get a page not found error...